# Como puedo habilitar la tecla tabulador en esta función?

Tags: jquery

Tengo esta función en JQuery pero al llegar a ese input ya no me funciona la tecla tabulador para pasar al siguiente input. Ya intente agregando otra condición en la que incluyo el código ASCII de la tecla mencionada (9).
Gracias por su apoyo.

```
$(function() {
        $('#contacto').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
            e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el HTML de los input?  Hay un atributo que quizás debas usar en alguna parte: tabindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No queda claro lo que necesitas. El tabulador como tecla para pasar de un input a otro es un comportamiento por defecto en los navegadores (no necesitarias programarlo).

Tu función lo que hace de hecho es cancelar el evento, ya que :

```
if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
```

El operador de negacion "!", esta haciendo que cualquier tecla que no sea las que validas con "key ==..." entren en el bloque con  **e.preventDefault()**

En fin, probaste con ?:

```
$(function () {
    $('#contacto').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if (!((key == 9) || (key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Me funciona ok.

-------------------EDIT---------------------------

Podría hacer esto, posiciónate sobre el elemento, luego ve a "Event Listeners", y desplegá "keydown", para ver cuantos disparadores hay asociados a ese input:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! perdona por no ser lo suficiente claro, recién comienzo con esto de la programación. Sucede que la función que tengo me bloquea el tabulador, previene su acción, he agregado tu sugerencia a mi código  y no me permite avanzar al siguiente input cuando presiono tabulador. Si ayuda de algo estoy trabajando con laravel 8

Comment: Cuando presionas el tabulador, el cursor, permanece en el input #contacto? Puedes ejecutar en la consola del navegador (despues de presionar TAB): "document.activeElement" , y  adjuntarnos el resultado?

Comment: Si, aun me mantiene el cursor en el mismo campo.

Comment: Entonces es posible que en alguna otra parte u otro script  este controlando tambien el evento. Podrias adjuntarnos mas codigo de tu proyecto?

Comment: ahi te edite la respuesta con información que puedes incluir.

Comment: Ya he revisado el código de pies a cabeza, y no tengo alguna otra función que controle el evento de ese input. Desconozco cual pueda ser la causa por la que suceda esto. Lo mas curioso que he probado ese script en un archivo aparte al proyecto y funciona bien.

Comment: Podrias adjuntar un print como el que adjunte en el edit de la respuesta?

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias con tu ayuda logre solucionarlo. El problema venia de otro script que me controlaba ese evento.

Comment: Pleno. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Este es el mensaje que me muestra en consola despues de ejecutar document.activeElement

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]/i.stack.imgur.com/MZ4KC.jpg